# Disable MXDW Printing Preferences programmatically

Tags: c#, printing, windows-7, xps, xpsviewer

There's a setting on Windows 7 to automatically open XPS files from MXDW:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adrianford/2008/08/20/automatically-opening-xps-files-from-mxdw/

Is there a way to change this checkbox setting through code? I'm using C#/VB.NET

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I've figured it out.

I used a registry comparison tool (regshot) to see what changes in the registry when I toggle this setting. It is:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\mxdwdui]
"OpenAfterCreation"
```

`DWORD 0x00000001 (1) means 'checked'`